# WinRT DataWriter, how to ensure all the bytes in the buffer are saved to the backing store

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, idisposable

System.IO.StreamWriter is guaranteed to save the bytes in the buffer when it is disposed. Like this

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\a.txt"))
{
   writer.WriteLine("Hello world."); 
}
```

The good thing about StreamWriter is that I can call its Dispose method from multiple threads without having to worry about data loss.

But for Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter, I have to call its StoreAsync method explicitly or the data is not saved to the file. The problem is, if a DataWriter has been disposed (from other thread), calling StoreAsync will throw an ObjectDisposedException. So I have to check whether the DataWriter has already been disposed of before calling StoreAsync. So my code looks like

```
try
{
    dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer);
}
catch(...)
{
     //...
}
finally
{
    lock (lockForDisposingDataWriter) 
    {
        if (!bDisposed) //Boolean flag indicating whether dataWriter has been disposed of
        {
            bDisposed = true;
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync(); //await operator is not allowed here
            dataWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The questions：

1. How to ensure the bytes in the DataWriter buffer are stored? I think calling StoreAsync in the finally block is inviting trouble, since 'await' is not allowed in a finally block.
2. If my solution can work, how to detect if a datawriter has been disposed of in a thread safe manner?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem in any case, because you need to await the `StoreAsync()` call before you call `Dispose()`.

In your code `StoreAsync()` might get executed in parallel with `Dispose()`.

You need to do this:

```
 await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
 dataWriter.Dispose();
```

Comment: yes, that's another problem I am trying to solve: 'await' operator cannot be used in the body of a lock statement, nor can it be used in a finally clause.

Comment: I guess you could do something like: dataWriter.StoreAsync().ContinueWith(() => dataWriter.Dispose());

Comment: not sure if this could help: dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask().Wait();